# Back to previous field when current field is empty using Shift+Tab

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form with 3 fields:

1. email
2. password
3. number

If EMAIL is empty, I can't go to PASSWORD field using press tab, 
only can go to next field if email not empty, actually it works,

When focus in PASSWORD field, I want to go back to EMAIL field using Shift+Tab. It only works when PASSWORD is not empty.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
  <form action="/action_page.php" method="post" name="subForm" id="subForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password">
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Number:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number" placeholder="Enter Number" name="number">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function disableinputs(){
    $("#subForm input").prop('readonly', true);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    disableinputs();
});
$(document).on('click','#subForm input',function(){
    $(this).prop('readonly', false);
});
$(document).on('focus','#subForm input',function(){
    $(this).prop('readonly', false);
});
$(document).on('focusout','#subForm input',function(){
    disableinputs();
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#email").focusout(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            $(this).focus();
        }
    });
    $("#password").focusout(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            $(this).focus();
        }
    });
    $("#number").focusout(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            $(this).focus();
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can it be accomplished ?

Comment: If you want to handle tab keys then you need to use keypress (or keydown) events, not blur events, as they will occur when you click outside the input.  If you change the default behaviour of the browser then people will find it unfamiliar and probably consider it broken.  I'd advise that you simply show a `This field cannot be empty` message next to required inputs when you leave them.  That doesn't change the default tab/shift+tab behaviour, but still prompts the user with their mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
  <form action="/action_page.php" method="post" name="subForm" id="subForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password">
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Number:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number" placeholder="Enter Number" name="number">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function disableinputs(){
    $("#subForm input").prop('readonly', true);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    disableinputs();
});
$(document).on('click','#subForm input',function(){
    $(this).prop('readonly', false);
});
$(document).on('focus','#subForm input',function(){
    $(this).prop('readonly', false);
});
$(document).on('focusout','#subForm input',function(){
    disableinputs();
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#email").focusout(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            $(this).focus();
        }
    });
    $("#password").focusout(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            $(this).focus();
            $("#email").focus();
        }
    });
    $("#number").focusout(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            $(this).focus();
            $("#number").focus();
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks sudhir, its actually works, but i want if user press shift+tab, no need to click mouse to edit field

Answer (score 0):

Well, to looks like you want to do the following:

- If password field is empty, you **should** be able to Shfit+Tab to email
- If password field is not empty, you **should** be able to Shift+Tab to email

So you always want to go to e-mail on Shift+Tab, so this code:

```
$("#password").focusout(function () {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

should be removed all together. You never want to stop user from Shift+Tab'ing from password.